# Uploading an image to Flask server

Tags: python, flask

I am struggling bit with Flask and uploading a file, here is my Flask code so far:

```
    @app.route('/api/user/update/', methods=['PUT'])
@auth.login_required
def update_user():
        # check if the post request has the file part
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=g.user.id,deleted=0).first()
    try:
        if 'uname' in request.args:
            user.username = request.args['uname']
        if 'password' in request.args:
            user.hash_password(request.args['password'])
        if 'lname' in request.args:
            user.lastname = request.args['lname']
        if 'fname' in request.args:
            user.firstname = request.args['fname']
        if 'address' in request.args:
            user.address = request.args['address']
        if 'preferance1' in request.args:
            user.pre1 = request.args['preferance1']
        if 'preferance2' in request.args:
            user.pre2 = request.args['preferance2']
        if 'preferance3' in request.args:
            user.pre3 = request.args['preferance3']
        if 'file' in request.files:
            file = request.files['file']
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            filename.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            #print(filename)
            #print(url_for('upload_file', filename=filename))
            user.image_filename = filename
            user.image_url = url_for('upload_file', filename=filename)
        db.session.commit()
    except:
        print("Error")
        db.session.rollback()
        db.session.flush()
    return jsonify({'user':user.serialize})
```

If I added anything as a file from Postman the request will failed and exception will be thrown. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write `file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))` instead of `filename.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))`. The `file` is a `File Storage` object. And the `filename` is only a str.